# Mono xbuild - can I prevent it doing a rebuild all each time?

Tags: mono, xbuild, raspberry-pi

I'm using mono and xbuild to compile and debug OpenTK on the Raspberry Pi. However every time I change a single line of code by running *xbuild OpenTK.sln /p:Configuration=Debug* it kicks off a rebuild all which takes about an hour to compile.

I can't find a switch anywhere in the command-line help, but wondered if anyone knew how to make xbuild only compile the modified files? Or is there something I can change in the project file's settings?

Comment: That's probably better asked on the mailing list - but there's no such switch, if the project files are poorly organised the whole solution will be rebuilt every time.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's the project/solution file settings that are causing the rebuild all, not xbuild itself?

Comment: Yes. And MSBuild/xbuild can't do incremental builds on `.cs` file level - it has to rebuild the whole assembly if a source file changes. The changes cascade through the dependencies, so a change in the source of an assembly early in the project dependency chain forces a full rebuild.

Comment: I see. Many thanks for the help, and it's starting to sound like I'm stuck with this long compile length then.